# imagemagick -morph: increase file number but not consecutive

Tags: linux, imagemagick

I've been using imagemagick for a few days. My objective is that I want to merge several screenshots into a video and I want to make a nice transition between frames. So I've found the -morph option, for example

```
convert original/*.jpg -morph 10 new/img%03d.jpg
```

which will create a total of 12 images, from `img001.jpg` to `img012.jpg`.

Is there a way that the images in the output be like, for example, one every X number? for example `img00X.jpg` `img00(x+x).jpg` and so on?

Comment: I am sure there is an easy answer to this but I don't understand your question... you have 2 original images (or do you have more?) and you want to morph between them in 10 steps, so you will have 12 output images - your first original, then 10 new ones and the final image? Is that correct? Are we supposed to make them into an animated GIF or something?

Comment: Are you going to respond to questions on this?

Comment: So, if in your original directory, you have a.jpg and b.jpg and c.jpg, what are you going to morph into what? a.jpg into b.jpg? Or a.jpg into c.jpg? Or what?

Comment: And if we find out what you are going to morph into what, if a.jpg is morphed into something and you save the 12 results as new/img001.jpg through new/img024.jpg, when I then morph b.jpg into something else for you, by your specification b.jpg will also morph on top of the morphed a.jpg because that too will morph into new/img001.jpg through new/img024.jpg.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well your requirements, you want to obtain:

`img002.jpg` `img004.jpg` `img006.jpg` ... `img024.jpg`

instead of:

`img001.jpg` `img002.jpg` `img003.jpg` ... `img012.jpg`

I'm not sure you can do it directly with imageMagick, however you can go to your `new` directory and type:

```
for i in `ls -r`;do mv $i `printf "img%03d.jpg" $(($(expr ${i:3:3} + 0)*2))`;done
```

*(I assume that there are no other files in this directory)*

Answer (score 1):

actually it is possible yet without leading zeroes. for example morph every png with 5 transitions steps and increments output counter by 3

```
im *.png -morph 5 -set filename:a %[fx:t*3] "output-%[filename:a].jpg"
```